# ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/knowledge-base'

Tags: angular, typescript

I'm setting up dynamic routing for my application in angular 6, and when I run the application there are no compile errors, but once I click on a link (say, knowledge base) it gives me the following error:

**core.js:1673 ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/knowledge-base'**

I followed the tutorials [Here](https://grokonez.com/frontend/angular/angular-6/angular-6-dynamic-navigation-bar-add-remove-route-dynamically) and [Here](https://medium.com/@DenysVuika/dynamic-routes-with-angular-6fda03b7fa2c) for applying dynamic routing to my application, which would allow `components` to create links, display them on screen and redirect when clicked. For testing I have created a `dummyComponent`, which would be used by every route initially, but will be replaced by actual `components` when this is working.

However, due to the error above, I was not able to go anywhere with this. I tried browsing through the current solutions and the most relevant ones were [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43036649/angular-2-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segment-a) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51884009/error-error-uncaught-in-promise-error-cannot-match-any-routes-url-segme), but they wouldn't really solve the problem I'm having. Am I missing something perhaps?

Here is my code:

**toolbar.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TranslatePipe } from 'src/app/pipes/translate/translate.pipe';
import { DynamicRoutingService } from 'src/app/services/dynamic-routing/dynamic-routing.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { DummyComponent } from 'src/app/views/dummy/dummy.component';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-toolbar',
  templateUrl: './toolbar.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./toolbar.component.scss'],
  providers: [DynamicRoutingService]
})

/**
* The purpose of this file is to provide the html template with the translated names
* for the categories in the toolbar.
*/
export class ToolbarComponent implements OnInit {

/**
* Object containing the translated names and their respective icons
* @property {array} links
*/
links: Array<{ text: string, path: string }>;

constructor(private translate: TranslatePipe, private router: Router, private dynamicRouting: DynamicRoutingService) {
    this.router.config.unshift(
      { path: 'knowledge-base', component: DummyComponent }, 
      { path: 'home', component: DummyComponent },
      { path: 'settings', component: DummyComponent }
    );
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "home", path: "home" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "knowledge_base", path: "knowledge-base" });
    this.dynamicRouting.addItem({ text: "settings", path: "settings" });
}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.links = [];
    let rawData = this.dynamicRouting.getLinks();
    let self = this;
    rawData.forEach(function(data) {
      let text = self.translate.transform("generic[toolbar][categories][" + data.text + "][label]");
      self.links.push({ text: text, path: data.path });
    });
  }

}
```

**toolbar.component.html**

```
<app-header
  [fixed]="true"
  [navbarBrandFull]="{src: 'assets/logo.png', width: 143, height: 36, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [navbarBrandMinimized]="{src: 'assets/logo2.png', width: 35, height: 35, alt: 'RT Logo'}"
  [sidebarToggler]="'lg'">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav d-md-down-none" routerLinkActive="active">
    <li class="nav-item px-3" *ngFor="let link of links">
      <a class="nav-link" [routerLink]="link.path">{{ link.text }}</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav ml-auto">
  </ul>
</app-header>
```

**dynamic-routing.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
/*
* This service will provide components with the ability to dynamically create
* routes within the application
*/
export class DynamicRoutingService {

  /*
  *
  * @property {array} links
  */
  private links = new Array<{ text: string, path: string, icon: string }>();

  constructor() { }

  /*
  * Method to fetch data
  *
  */
  getLinks() {
    return this.links;
  }

  /*
  * Method to store data
  * @param text, path, icon
  */
  addItem({ text, path, icon = null }) {
    this.links.push({ text: text, path: path, icon: icon });
  }

  /*
  * Method to remove a specific link0
  * @param text
  */
  removeItem({ text }) {
    this.links.forEach((link, index) => {
      if (link.text === text) {
        this.links.splice(index, 1);
      }
    });
  }

  /*
  * Remove all links from the array
  */
  clearAll() {
    this.links.length = 0;
  }
}
```

**app.routing.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';


import { LoginComponent } from './views/login/login.component';
import { MainComponent } from './views/main/main.component';
import { AuthGuardService } from './services/auth-guard/auth-guard.service';

export const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: LoginComponent,

  },
  { path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

**Expected**: Links should properly redirect to a route eg."main/name"

**Actual**:

```
ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/home'
Error: Cannot match any routes. URL Segment: 'main/home'
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1384)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at ApplyRedirects.push../node_modules/@angular/router/fesm5/router.js.ApplyRedirects.noMatchError (router.js:1384)
    at CatchSubscriber.selector (router.js:1365)
    at CatchSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/catchError.js.CatchSubscriber.error (catchError.js:34)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._error (Subscriber.js:80)
    at MapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.error (Subscriber.js:60)
    at TapSubscriber.push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/operators/tap.js.TapSubscriber._error (tap.js:61)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:814)
    at resolvePromise (zone.js:771)
    at zone.js:873
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:421)
    at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:3811)
    at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:420)
    at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:188)
    at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:595)
    at ZoneTask.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask [as invoke] (zone.js:500)
    at invokeTask (zone.js:1540)
defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:1673
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.ErrorHandler.handleError @ core.js:1719
next @ core.js:4311
schedulerFn @ core.js:3551
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub @ Subscriber.js:196
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.SafeSubscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:134
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber._next @ Subscriber.js:77
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subscriber.js.Subscriber.next @ Subscriber.js:54
push../node_modules/rxjs/_esm5/internal/Subject.js.Subject.next @ Subject.js:47
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.EventEmitter.emit @ core.js:3535
(anonymous) @ core.js:3842
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke @ zone.js:388
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run @ zone.js:138
push../node_modules/@angular/core/fesm5/core.js.NgZone.runOutsideAngular @ core.js:3779
onHandleError @ core.js:3842
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.handleError @ zone.js:392
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runGuarded @ zone.js:154
_loop_1 @ zone.js:677
api.microtaskDrainDone @ zone.js:686
drainMicroTaskQueue @ zone.js:602
push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneTask.invokeTask @ zone.js:500
invokeTask @ zone.js:1540
globalZoneAwareCallback @ zone.js:1566
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not defining any child route paths for `/main`. That is the reason you are getting that error. From what you have written, you can only route to `/main`. Add the following :

You can either register different path directly as `main/:somePath` or add child routes to `/main`

Method 1

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main',
    component: MainComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthGuardService],
    pathMatch : 'full'
  },
  { path: 'main/:somePath',
    component: MainComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
  }
];
```

Method 2 :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'main',
    children :[
       {path: ':somePath', component: MainComponent}
    ],
    component: SomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: '',
    component: AppComponent,
  },
];
```

**NOTE** : Always add empty route path at the end. So that it will allow to match more specific routes first. Or else you will have to use `pathMatch:'full'`

Comment: This kind of solved the current problem, but others popped up.

 1. This example is only using MainComponent, meaning any link I click on would be redirected to MainComponent, while in reality I may be using multiple components at different links. If I add them manually here then what would be the point of dynamic routing.

2.  When I click the first time (eg. home), the link redirects to `main/home`, but when I click it again it redirects to `main/home/home` instead of `main/home`, why is this happening?

Comment: What I understand from the concept of dynamic routing is you add route paths dynamically (i.e register paths along with the component name) after some event or based on the state of an application. Still you are mentioning the component here, without which angular wont understand what to render. And coming to your second problem can you elaborate bit more? or create a stackblitz example to demonstrate

Comment: 'Still you are mentioning the component here', couldn't understand this, did you mean 'I have to mention it here?'. If so then what is the point of adding `router.config.unshift` to the **toolbar.component.ts** in the tutorial, could you please explain? For the second problem, suppose I have a `navbar` with the links shown above. The navbar remains on every screen. I'm at **url/main** and I click "home", it redirects to **url/main/home**. When I click "home" again on the navbar it goes to **url/main/home/home** and throws the same error above. Why is that happening?

Comment: Dynamic routing is simply adding/removing route definitions within the application which is handled by Router service. If you read the line from tutorial link it says `You can use this approach for scenarios, which require new routes based on conditions, or completely different components for the same route. That should also help with unit testing, as you can populate route collection on the fly before or during the test run.` Its just about registering the routes dynamically upon some events. `Still you are mentioning the component here` because any route definition should have component name